# UItabBarController событие - переход к другому tab

Tags: xcode, ios7

Всем привет!

Имеется uitabbarcontroller и 2-мя табами. В первом табе, есть uinavigationcontroller (+uitableviewcontroller), который переключает на другие view.

Так вот задача:
Необходимо сделать так, что бы при переключении на 2-й таб, в 1-м табе navigationcontroller "поднимал" view до root. То есть обеспечить, что при выборе 1-го таба, всегда будет отображаться root view, а уже потом ручками переходить во вложенные view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В методе делегата UITabBarController сделай:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ( [viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]] )
    {
        [(UINavigationController *)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
```

или проверь с своими контролами, и вызывай для UINavigationController `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`

Comment: Александр, ага... Идея правильная...

Можно усложнить задачу (это просто на будущее для понимания), а что если в обоих табах будет UINavigationController? и во втором трогать ничего не надо?

Comment: тогда просто сравнивай [viewController isEqual:tabBarController.viewControllers[0]]

Comment: Спасибо! Лего собралось в голове :)